# Coq: Non-list Data structures living in Set?

Tags: functional-programming, coq, dependent-type, theorem-proving

If I have the following line:

```
Definition Foo : Set := list nat.
```

then I compile with no problems.

However, suppose I want to do the same with `Coq.Lists.ListSet`, a library representing finite sets as lists:

```
(*Section first_definitions.
 Variable A : Type.
Definition listset := list A.*)
Definition Bar : Set := listset nat.
```

I get the following error:

```
The term "listset nat" has type "Type" while it is expected to have type 
"Set" (universe inconsistency).
```

1. Is there a way to "cast" `listset` so that it lives in `Set` instead of `Type`? i.e. If I know I'm going to be using `listset` with parameters of type `Set`, is there a way to make it live in the `Set` heirarchy somehow?
2. Why does the error happen for `listset`, but not for `list`, when `listset` is defined to be `list`?

*Note*: The actual type is called `set`, but I've renamed it to `listset` to avoid confusion with the sort `Set`.

EDIT: `=` replaced with `:=`

Comment: @larsr My bad, I was trying to get a MWE for the question. I've updated it with more context (i.e. section Variables) and fixed the `=` and `:=` confusion

Comment: Just FYI: for the MWE I think it would be more helpful to import ListSet so we know exactly what definition you're using. As far as `set` vs `Set`, I think most Coq users are used to case sensitivity and wouldn't get confused. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 2. Why does the error happen for listset, but not for list, when listset is defined to be list?

Because `list` is a [*template universe polymorphic*](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/cic.html?highlight=extype_ind#template-polymorphism) inductive definition (see `About list.`), which in this case means that if `list` is applied to a type in `Set`, the result is still in `Set`.

> 1. Is there a way to "cast" `listset` so that it lives in `Set` instead of `Type`?

AFAIK, there is no way to make definitions template universe polymorphic, but you can make them [*universe polymorphic*](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/universe-polymorphism.html#polymorphic-universes) like so:

```
Polymorphic Definition listset (A : Type) : Type := list A.
Check listset nat : Set.
```

One more option is to use `Set Universe Polymorphism` command so you won't need to prepend your definitions with the `Polymorphic` keyword.
This feature has experimental status at the time of writing. And it does not apply retroactively, so I guess you would need to fork your own `ListSet`.

Comment: Is there a way to use a definition in a Universe Polymorphic way if it wasn't initially declared as such and I have no control over its declaration? i.e. if I'm trying to use [ListSet from the stdlib](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Lists.ListSet.html)?

Comment: I think it's not possible. Also, some people say `Set` is legacy. I'm curious: what's your use case?

Comment: I'm using Ott to generate definitions and LaTeX from a language file, and it generates `Set` everywhere. I'll probably just run a post-processor to change `Set` to `Type`, or do something awful like `Definition Set := Type` if Coq will let me. I wasn't aware that `Set` was legacy, that's good to know.

Comment: You could probably reuse [Coq.Logic.SetIsType](https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/bd0a681350b1bc8947d6d7603dc6a9759f0c7897/theories/Logic/SetIsType.v#L19)'s approach.

Comment: Perfect, looks like just what I need!