# Use False_rec to build an aliased list type in Coq

Tags: coq

I'd like to create a dependent function, but I am running into a type mismatch error on the `False_rec` term. I'm trying to do something similar to the following:

```
Definition env A := list A.

Fixpoint zip (xs ys : env nat) (H : length xs = length ys) : env (nat * nat).
Proof.
  refine
  (match xs, ys with
  | [], [] => []
  | x :: xs, y :: ys =>
      (x, y) :: zip xs ys _
  | _, _ => False_rec _ _
  end).
...
```

However, I receive the following error:

```
The term "False_rec ?P ?f" has type "?P" while it is expected to have type 
"env (nat * nat)" (unable to find a well-typed instantiation for 
"?P": cannot ensure that "Type" is a subtype of "Set").
```

The standard list, when it is given a Set, becomes a set itself, but it seems that it does not do so when aliased in this way. For example:

```
Check (list nat). (* list nat : Set *)
Check (env nat). (* env nat : Type *)
```

Is there a reason for this mismatch? And is there a way to work around it? (For example, can I convince Coq that `(env nat)` is a `Set`? Or can I use a more general `False_rec` function that operates on `Type` instead of `Set`?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a reason for this mismatch?

Yes. `Type` is an entity that can contain (big) things that won't fit into `Set`. E.g. `nat` fits into `Set`, but `Set` does not fit into itself. I think there should be more than one excellent answers on SO explaining this issue.

> (For example, can I convince Coq that `(env nat)` is a `Set`?

You can use explicit type annotations:

```
Definition env (A : Set) : Set := list A.
```

> Or can I use a more general `False_rec` function that operates on `Type` instead of `Set`?

Yes, you can. It's called `False_rect`.

Observe that simple `match`-expression won't work in your case (regardless of `Set`/`Type` business), you will need to use dependent pattern matching. Another possibility is to use proof mode to define your function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still have one question: why is `list nat` of type `Set` but `env nat` is a `Type`? I cannot use a type annotation in the definition of `env` in my work, because `env` is defined in a library.

Comment: Please take a look at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51277444/2747511) and my answer to it. HTH